# Kubernetes nginx ingress configuration for wildcard rule

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am struggling with the following issues. I have 2 services running. I am using a wildcard for handling subdomains. See the example conf below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: web-static-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: www.foo.bar
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  name: foo-bar-ingress
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: '*.foo.bar'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: legacy-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: foo.bar
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: new-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Using the app in the way that abc.foo.bar -> legacy-service and foo.bar -> new-service work perfectly fine. However, when I access the app with www prefix, it gets under the wildcard subdomain path, meaning [www.foo.bar](http://www.foo.bar) goes into legacy-service, which is what I want to avoid. AFAIU this "www" is caught by this asterisk regexp and goes in the wrong way. I would like it go to new-service.

Is there any way I can achieve this with the nginx ingress configuration?

Comment: According to this page, extensions/v1beta1 API version for Ingress is no longer served:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122
Could you please try to update it to the newest one?

Comment: updating doesn't help here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also redirecting requests from `www.foo.bar` can be achieved by also specifying the hostname. Please note that the order of the hosts does matter as they are translated into the Envoy filter chain. Therefore, the wildcard host should be the last host.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: web-static-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: www.foo.bar
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  name: foo-bar-ingress
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'foo.bar'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: new-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: 'www.foo.bar'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: new-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: '*.foo.bar'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: legacy-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Comment: But that doesn't help either. The config is valid, but the *.foo.bar rules over the prefixed www version, unfortunately

Comment: @AdamSoliński have you tried changing the order of the host definition. Might defining the wildcard host at the end could help here as this configuration is translated into envoy filters and the envoy proxies have a filter chain where the order is important.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jonas, now that works, I haven't realised that these are translated into envoy filters which are then chained in an ordered way.

Comment: @AdamSoliński nice to hear that it worked. Asking to mark the answer as accepted that other users can also see it. I edited the comment with the correct order and a short remark